# How to add auto slash in date in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement date field similar to [this](https://appleid.apple.com/account) page with date format of `yyyy/mm/dd` in react.

This is what i have tried

```
const [date_of_birth,setDateofBirth] = useState("");
const handleChangeDOB = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    value = value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    if(value.length >= 6){
      value = `${value.slice(0, 4)}/${value.slice(4, 6)}/${value.slice(6)}`;
    }
    else if(value.length >= 4){
      value = `${value.slice(0, 4)}/${value.slice(4)}`;
    }
    setDateofBirth(value);
}
```

```
<input type="text" maxLength={10} value={date_of_birth} onChange={handleChangeDOB} placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"/>
```

When ever i try to delete it does not work correctly. If delete from in between then there can be two slash. What else I have to do to make it work ?

Comment: you can use mask library to automatically handle slashes. if you want to avoid libraries then please check this - https://dev.to/juanmanuelcrego/input-mask-in-react-without-libraries-5akf

Comment: In the `handleChangeDOB` function where you are assigning `value` twice in the first if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is  this solution enough: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-engelbart-0pcpep?file=/src/App.js

Im using the react-input-mask to handle the masking logic.

```
      <InputMask
        mask="9999/99/99"
        maskChar=""
        value={date_of_birth}
        onChange={handleChangeDOB}
        placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"
      />
```

The docs for the component are  here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask

Answer (score 0):

```js
-There are different ways to convert date to yyyy / mm / dd format in React.One way is to use the date - fns library, which allows you to customize your own format.For example:

  import {
    format
  } from 'date-fns';
console.log(format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd kk:mm:ss'))

  
-Another way is to use the Intl.DateTimeFormat object, which formats a date according to the locale and options you specify.For example:

  const today = Date.now();
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit'
}).format(today));


-You can also use the moment library, which provides a simple way to format dates.For example:

  import moment from 'moment';
console.log(moment(yourDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD kk:mm:ss"));
I hope this helps you with your code conversion.
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, Here is what you can do.
This is for checking value function.

```
const checkValue = (str, max) => {
      if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
        var num = parseInt(str);
        if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
        str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) 
               && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
      };
      return str;
    };
```

And here is the event listener for your input.

```
const handleChangeDOB = (e) => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  if (/\D\/$/.test(value)) value = value.substr(0, value.length - 3);
  let values = value.split("/").map(function (v) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, "");
  });
  if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
  if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
  let output = values.map(function (v, i) {
    return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + " / " : v;
  });
  setDateofBirth(output.join("").substr(0, 14));
};
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Is this not working?

Comment: How about the year?